# With the « tant que » construction, is it acceptable not to use the future tense?

Tags: temps-grammatical, conjonctions

> {I said}: On ne **pourra** pas passer les portes tant qu’ils n'**auront** pas **fini** de fouiller nos affaires. C’est à croire qu’on fait la queue à la douane !

With the « tant que » construction, I wonder if it is acceptable not to use the future tense and say:

> On ne **peut** pas passer les portes tant qu’ils n'**ont** pas **fini** de fouiller nos affaires. C’est à croire qu’on fait  la queue à la douane !

Comment: I use the present tense more often than the future with "tant que", so yes it's acceptable :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hi. It's been quite a while on this site! I'd been travelling in Switzerland for nearly two months. I sent you a mail after I got back from the trip if you haven't noticed it yet. :) {This comment to be deleted after a while}

Comment: No I haven't ! I'll check and continue the conversation there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut employer le futur ou le présent mais j'y vois une différence de sens.

**Futur**

> On ne pourra pas passer les portes tant qu'ils n'auront pas fini de fouiller nos affaires.

Je parle de la situation présente que je suis en train de vivre, d'un fait ponctuel. Je suis en train de faire la queue pour passer la douane quand je dis cette phrase, et je n'implique pas que c'est toujours la même chose.

**Présent**

> On ne peut pas passer les portes tant qu'ils n'ont pas fini de fouiller nos affaires.

Cette phrase peut décrire une situation que je suis en train de vivre, mais je peux aussi la dire sans être forcément en train de faire la queue pour passer la douane parce que l'emploi du présent reflète une vérité générale, je signifie que cette situation est habituelle.

Comment: Merci. The "une vérité générale" in your explanation made me think: How would things be different if the subject were "je"?

Comment: @Alone-zee Personnellement je perçois toujours la même différence quel que soit le pronom employé, une des valeurs du présent (et c'est la même chose en anglais) est la généralisation. « (À chaque fois que je prends l'avion)  je ne peux pas passer les portes tant qu'ils n'ont pas fini de fouiller mes affaires ». You wouldn't have *À chaque fois* with the verbs in the future, unless you wanted to point to a change in procedure that will make things different in the future.

Answer (score 1):

En utilisant le futur, on se laisse une chance :
" on ne pourra pas passer les portes tant qu'ils n'auront pas fini de fouiller nos affaires." Mais sait-on jamais ? S'ils ne fouillaient pas, ou pas la totalité ? Le futur n'est pas gravé.

Avec le présent on fait un constat maintenant. C'est sans espoir :  "On ne peut pas passer les portes tant qu'ils n'ont pas fini de fouiller nos affaires." Ils ont déjà commencé.c'est trop tard pour que ça change.